# showing ASCII code in C

Tags: c, ascii

I have problem with program - I compile it and run, first line shows in console, but when i put any character and press Enter program just crash (not responding Windows says).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int e;
char ch;
printf("\n Enter a character : ");
scanf("%c",ch);
e=ch;
printf("\n The ASCII value of the character is : %d",e);
getch();
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c",ch);` is wrong, google for how to use `scanf`.

Comment: Change to `scanf("%c", &ch);` `scanf` wants a pointer

Comment: @Xenix, but you need to learn something else from this. How to debug a program. You should have commented out, from the bottom, line after line, until the program did not crash anymore. This will put you on a path of success. This is why you got so many down votes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to

```
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

`scanf` does not need the value of the variable, it needs the variable itself to write to it, therefore `scanf` needs the address of `ch`and not the value of `ch`.

Comment: @Prof.Falken, I have been faster :P